# Setting Image To The UITabbar in iphone?

Tags: ios, uitabbar

I am new to ios development.
I created `UITabbar` programatically and set its delegate to self. All functions well. But my tabbar consists three tab bar items. I have given different images to the different tab bar items. But they all shows another image.

This is my code:

```
UITabbarItem item1 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"item1" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imagename"] tag:1];
```

Comment: Did you added them to tabbar using `[tabBar setItems:tabItemsArray];`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
UIImage *selectedImage0 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tab-selected.png"];
UIImage *unselectedImage0 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tab-unselected.png"];

[item1 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage0 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage0];
```